# Extracting one column out of a knex transaction query result

Tags: knex.js

I have an async function to do the following knex transaction (on a MySQL db): query a table for all rows with a certain range on a particular column; update the column value for all of those rows; return *all* columns of all of those rows:

```
        try { 
            let queryResult
            let trxResult

            trxResult = await dbConn.transaction(async (trx) => {

                queryResult = await trx(tbl).select('*')
                    .whereNull('published').orWhere('published', '<', '2100000000')

                // Somehow use a .whereIn() here?
                for (let i: number = 0; i < queryResult.length; i++) {
                    await trx.into(tbl).where('_id', queryResult[i]._id).update({ published: Math.round(new Date().valueOf() / 1000) })
                }

            });

            console.log("transaction was committed");
            return ( queryResult )
        } 

        catch (e) {
            console.log(`transaction was rolled back\n${e}`);
        }

    }
```

This code works, but for efficiency (one SQL operation), I'd like to use a 'whereIn' instead of running round the 'for' loop. 
Is there a way I can extract from queryResult the "_id" column values for use in a whereIn().update() ? 
Without losing the original result - i.e. *all* columns - which the function needs to return

Answer (score 0):

Occurred to me, after stepping away for a few minutes (always the way!) that this is more of a JavaScript question than knex, just parsing the object:

```
                const result = queryResult.map(({ _id }) => _id)
                await trx.into(tbl).whereIn('_id', result).update({ published: Math.round(new Date().valueOf() / 1000) })
```